# Jenkins slackSend: channel alert notifications for @here or specific user

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, slack

Jenkins **slackSend** question: How to perform an alert notification to a channel that has received a message that needs to be addressed by either any member **@here** or a specific person ex **@Jane.Doe**?

Reviewed Jenkins Slack notifications: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/slack/

Tried adding **@here** to the beginning of **slackSend** message:

```
failure {
    script {
        slackSend(
            color: "#FF0000",
            channel: "${SLACK_CHANNEL}",
            message: "@home FAILED"
        )
    }
}
```

However, adding **@here** to **slackSend** message does not initiate alert notification for that channel.

Suggestions?

Note: Received a comment from a coworker, I am investigating this path:

> thought I remember needing to do a look up on users to get an ID and then some special syntax it parses into a username. been a while though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you must find the ID of the user and then mention it in the the message, like this example:

```
def userId = slackUserIdFromEmail('spengler@ghostbusters.example.com')
slackSend(color: "good", message: "<@$userId> Message from Jenkins Pipeline")
```

Reference: https://plugins.jenkins.io/slack/

Edit:

If you want a put a special or a group mention, you only need follow the format guideline what can you see here : https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting#special-mentions

Comment: Sure, for special mentions only you need follow the format, i edit the answer with a reference from official docs of slack api.

Comment: For "@here" use:  <!here>

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
def emailWithoutDomain = env.BUILD_USER_EMAIL.replaceAll("@.*","").trim()
```

slackSend ( message: 'I want to mention <@${emailWithoutDomain}> this @user as part of message', teamDomain: '', token: '', channel: '' )