# Jenkins Pipeline: Which condition should I use to be notified about build failure?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline for automation tests in which it downloads the source from Git and builds it before starting to test.

I would like to have a slack notification when a Jenkins pipeline build fails.

Not if there are test errors - only if the code does not build.

The post conditions I found are as follows:

```
always  - Always, regardless of the outcome of stage/pipeline.

changed - If completion status differs from the previous run.

fixed   - When status went from failed or unstable to successful.

regression - When status was successful in the previous run but is failure, unstable or aborted now.

aborted - When the status is aborted.

failure - When the status is failure.

success - When the status is success.

unstable - When the status is unstable.

unsuccessful - When the status is not success, but any one of the others.

cleanup - Always, regardless of the outcome, but as the last one after all others have been run.
```

I don't see here a condition of build failure or something related.

Is there a way to achieve that? Does failure condition contains also build failures?

So far I used:

```
post{
    failure{
        slackSend( channel: "#my_alerts", token: "slack_webhook token", color: "good", message: "${custom_msg()}")
    }
}
```

but is it relevant to use failure condition?

Comment: Typically failure reports if anything in the pipeline fails. Afaik this is the one that must be used in post block to report failure

Answer (score 1):

We have a setup like this:
[image]

If the whole build fails, then we will be notified by the `failure` step in the `post` section.

**EDIT:**

````py
def onBuildAborted() {
    env.BUILD_STATUS = "build was aborted by user :stop_sign:";
    env.BUILD_TYPE = "INFO";
}

def onBuildSucceeded() {
    env.BUILD_STATUS = "build succeeded :check:";
    env.BUILD_TYPE = "SUCCESS";
}

def onBuildFailed() {
    env.BUILD_STATUS = "build failed :cross_mark:";
    env.BUILD_TYPE = "ERROR";
}

def onBuildSucceededButUnstable() {
    env.BUILD_STATUS = "build succeeded, but tests did not pass :prohibited:";
    env.BUILD_TYPE = "WARNING";
}

def notifyBuildEnd() {
    String buildStatus = env.BUILD_STATUS != null ? env.BUILD_STATUS : ""
    String resultType = env.BUILD_TYPE != null ? env.BUILD_TYPE : "";

    String buildDuration = currentBuild.durationString;
    buildDuration = buildDuration.replace(" and counting", "");
    // remove 'and counting' at end of string

    String messageHeader = "${buildStatus} in ${buildDuration}";
    String messageBody = env.BUILD_TESTRESULTS != null ? env.BUILD_TESTRESULTS : "";
    String stacktrace = env.BUILD_STACKTRACE != null ? env.BUILD_STACKTRACE : "";

    sendNotification(resultType, messageHeader, messageBody, stacktrace);
}

def sendNotification(String type = 'INFO', String header = 'update', String body = '', String stacktrace = '') {
    echo "preparing to send messaging platform notifications: type=${type}, header=${header}, body=${body}, stacktrace=${stacktrace}"

    // colors taken from bootstrap (see https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/bootstrap-colors)
    String color_neutral = '#17a2b8';  // teal
    String color_success = '#28a745';  // green
    String color_error = '#dc3545';    // red
    String color_warning = '#ffc107';  // yellow
    String color_default = ' #007bff'; // blue

    String messagecolor = color_default

    if ('SUCCESS' == type) {
        messagecolor = color_success;

    } else if ('INFO' == type) {
        messagecolor = color_neutral;

    } else if ('WARNING' == type) {
        messagecolor = color_warning;

    } else if ('ERROR' == type) {
        messagecolor = color_error;
    }

    def jobName = env.JOB_NAME;
    jobName = jobName.replace("%2F", "/");
    jobName = jobName.replace("%23", "#");

    def jobIdentifier = "<${env.BUILD_URL}|${jobName} - build ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}>"

    header = "*${header}*"
    if ("" != stacktrace) {
        stacktrace = "```${stacktrace}```"
    }

    def attachmentsArr = [
            [
                    text : header,
                    color: messagecolor
            ],
            [
                    text : jobIdentifier,
                    color: messagecolor
            ],
            [
                    text : body,
                    color: color_neutral
            ],
            [
                    text : stacktrace,
                    color: color_neutral
            ]
    ];

    def markdownJobIdentifier = "[${jobName} - build #${env.BUILD_NUMBER}](${env.BUILD_URL})"
    zulipSend message: "${header}\n${markdownJobIdentifier}\n${body}", stream: 'jenkins', topic: 'some_zulip_channel'

    echo "messaging platform notifications sent"
}
````

This will give you messages like this:
[image]

The only thing you need to change is zulipSend to slackSend.
If you need help with the slackSend command try [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68668675/jenkins-slacksend-channel-alert-notifications-for-here-or-specific-user).

Comment: can you please post the code? Not the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Any failure in the Pipeline will trigger the `failure{}` block. Even if your test execution throws an error the build will be marked as Failed. Basically at the end of the Pipeline Stage executions, based on `currentBuild.result` the relevant book will be executed.

Having said that, so the behavior really depends on how you have implemented your Pipeline. For example, if you don't want test execution to mark your build as a failure you will have to handle it explicitly. Something like below. So if the tests fail the build will be marked as `Unstable` and the unstable block will be executed.

```
stage('Test') { 
     steps {
        script {
            try {
                echo "Executing your tests here"
         
            } catch(e) {                                            
                currentBuild.result = "UNSTABLE"
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So, you actually say that even on code compilation\build error "failure" will be triggered?

Comment: I can't really say without looking at your Pipeline. It depends on the way you execute and the plugins you use. For example, if you are using a shell step to execute maven, maven will return an exit code 1 if the build fails (Compilation or Test failure), so Jenkins will detect this as a build failure.

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience in Jenkins this is the way to use post conditions. Usually only email or slack notification is sent when the build fails hence u should be using a failure condition like you have mentioned.

```
 post {  
     always {  
         echo 'This will always run'  
     }  
     success {  
         echo 'This will run only if successful'  
     }  
     failure {  
         mail bcc: '', body: "<b>Example</b><br>Project: ${env.JOB_NAME} <br>Build Number: ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} <br> URL de build: ${env.BUILD_URL}", cc: '', charset: 'UTF-8', from: '', mimeType: 'text/html', replyTo: '', subject: "ERROR CI: Project name -> ${env.JOB_NAME}", to: "foo@foomail.com";  
     }  
     unstable {  
         echo 'This will run only if the run was marked as unstable'  
     }  
     changed {  
         echo 'This will run only if the state of the Pipeline has changed'  
         echo 'For example, if the Pipeline was previously failing but is now successful'  
     }  
 }
```

As per documentation of Jenkins

**failure**
Only run the steps in post if the current Pipeline’s or stage’s run has a "failed" status, typically denoted by red in the web UI.

**success**
Only run the steps in post if the current Pipeline’s or stage’s run has a "success" status, typically denoted by blue or green in the web UI.

**unstable**
Only run the steps in post if the current Pipeline’s run has an "unstable" status, usually caused by test failures, code violations, etc.

I have noticed  unstable builds when JUnit publisher is configured and a test fails then the build will be marked unstable or If package scan fails to meet a threshold which it should have met.As per your scenario I feel failure post condition would be the best to use.